# GtkToolButton are disabled by default in glade3 + pygtk

Tags: python, toolbar, pygtk, gtk3, glade

I've created a simple app skeleton in python 2.7 using pyGtk and Glade (3.16.1) on Ubiuntu 14.04 LTS.
I've added a ToolBar and some buttons, but the gtkToolButton are always disabled. How can I enable them from Glade?

[image: my gui with toolbutton disabled]
[my gui with toolbutton disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABmjQ.png)

I've tried also in python using "set_sensitive" but nothing works.

Can You help me? Thank You very much!

This is a snippet from glade file:

```
<child>
      <object class="GtkToolbar" id="toolbar1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="toolbar_style">both-horiz</property>
        <property name="show_arrow">False</property>
        <style>
            <class name="primary-toolbar"/>
        </style>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkToolButton" id="toolbutton1">
            <property name="name">bt1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="is_important">True</property>
            <property name="action_name">bt1</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">toolbutton1</property>
            <property name="use_underline">True</property>
            <property name="stock_id">gtk-connect</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_toolbutton1_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

GtkToolbars are not very straightforward to use. You have to create a corresponding action. This is a simple example of how to use them:

The glade file:

```
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.16"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkToolbar">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkToolButton">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="action_name">app.zoom</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">zoom</property>
            <property name="use_underline">True</property>
            <property name="stock_id">gtk-zoom-in</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="homogeneous">True</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

The python file:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio

class Application(Gtk.Application):

    def do_activate(self):
        action = Gio.SimpleAction.new('zoom', None)
        action.connect('activate', self.on_zoom)
        self.add_action(action)

        builder = Gtk.Builder.new_from_file('window.glade')
        window = builder.get_object('window')
        window.show_all()
        self.add_window(window)

    def on_zoom(self, action, param):
        print('clicked')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().run()
```

You can also have a look at an [example for the application menu](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/application.html) as it is similar